# Function logic not behaving as intended

Tags: javascript

Good afternoon,

I'm working on a task list and I've run into some problems with my `removeTask` function.  I'm trying to make it so if there are no more tasks to delete, then do not show my `taskList` `filterDiv` and `clearBtn`.  What is actually happening is when there is nothing else to remove, it shows my `taskList` style still.

I've also noticed that clicking outside of the remove button will hide my task values even if tasks are **not** removed.  Can someone help me understand why my logic isn't working? Any help is appreciated!

```
function removeTask(e) {
    if (e.target.parentElement.classList.contains('delete-item')) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
            e.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
        }
    } else {
        taskList.style.display = 'none';
        clearBtn.style.display = 'none';
        filterDiv.style.display = 'none';
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

I've created a **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ksupuzbp/)** as code snippet wouldn't load everything correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently doing it via an else on remove. This clearly won't work as once you've removed it that function won't go to the else. You'll have to do it once you've removed the element instead:

```
function removeTask(e) {
    if (e.target.parentElement.classList.contains('delete-item')) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
            e.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
            if(document.querySelectorAll('.collection-item').length === 0){
              taskList.style.display = 'none';
              clearBtn.style.display = 'none';
              filterDiv.style.display = 'none';            
            }
        }
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1m04dLfj/

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was working under the assumption that if the class list didn't exist - then it would move to my else.

Comment: instead of what you have in `if`, I had `if(!taskList.firstChild)..` any idea why it didn't work?

Comment: Console log taskList.firstChild and it's likely a text element or something else. While my answer actually searches for that specific class.

Comment: @MathewBerg yeah it's giving something like `"                "`

Comment: Right and `!" "` will result in false since `" "` is a value (a space)

Comment: @MathewBerg why does it return that (" ") though? sorry not very experienced with DOM/JS

Comment: I can't see your dom but look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/vkcfruje/ even if there's no actual element, having text (which a space is a part of) is still considered a node.

Comment: @MathewBerg my DOM is exactly same as fiddle from OP's question.

Comment: Exactly... there are tabs/return characters etc... those are all text nodes.

Comment: @MathewBerg Yeah I checked there was return etc... thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First glance - seems like you missing a check if list is empty after removing a task :)

```
function removeTask(e) {
    if (e.target.parentElement.classList.contains('delete-item')) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
            e.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
      if (taskList.length = 0) taskList.style.display = 'none';
        }
    } else {
        taskList.style.display = 'none';
        clearBtn.style.display = 'none';
        filterDiv.style.display = 'none';

    }
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

You might wanna recheck rest of actions you do on else, do they belong here as well?

Answer (score 0):

After you remove the single task from the list of tasks, you need to check for the condition if it doesn't have any more items. If not, then hide the elements. I also updated the jsFiddle

```
function removeTask(e) {
    if (e.target.parentElement.classList.contains('delete-item')) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
            e.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
            if(taskList.children.length <=0) {
              taskList.style.display = 'none';
              clearBtn.style.display = 'none';
              filterDiv.style.display = 'none';
            }

        }
    } else {
        taskList.style.display = 'none';
        clearBtn.style.display = 'none';
        filterDiv.style.display = 'none';

    }
    e.preventDefault();
}
```